# How to define case-insensitivity for only a subsection of lexer tokens?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

Is there a way to do something like the following so the case-sensitivity is not an "all-or-nothing" option?

```
lexer grammar TestLexer;
options { caseInsensitive=true; } // ok, but it's not supported in the VS Code editor ??
BOOL: (TRUE|FALSE);

// I want these two keywords to be case-insensitive
TRUE:   'true'; // true, True, TRUE, ...
FALSE:  'false'; // false, False, FALSE, ...

options { caseInsensitive=false; } // ok, but it's not supported in the VS Code editor ??
// This keyword must only match exact case
YIELD:    'yield'; // 'yield' ONLY
```

If not, what is a possible way to do this? The way that I've seen before -- in my opinion is the worst choice -- is doing this kind of thing:

```
TRUE: T R U E  // case-insensitive
YIELD: 'yield' // case-sensitive
```

Comment: To answer this, we'd need to know what you'd want `Yield` to produce (as an example).  Is it a token recognition error, or (more likely) a match of some sort of `ID` rule that's not shown here?

Comment: @MikeCargal could ou please clarify? `YIELD: 'yield'` is just to match the literal `yield` and not `YIELD` or `Yield` or any case variation.

Comment: right, but IF you came across the "Yield" sequence of characters, would you want a Tokenization error, or would you want it to generate something like an `ID` token?

Comment: never mind... I just learned something... it looks like you can set this option selective ly (at least according to the documentation I've linked to in the answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation [here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/e1455c06f0b330a49a67361c8df9f242aa877059/doc/lexer-rules.md#caseinsensitive), it appears that you can set caseInsensitivity on a rule by rule basis.

The example given:

```
options { caseInsensitive=true; }
STRING options { caseInsensitive=false; } : 'N'? '\'' (~'\'' | '\'\'')* '\''; // lower n is not allowed
```

Answer (score 0):

From Mike's answer, this is what worked for me:

```
lexer grammar TestLexer;
options { caseInsensitive=true; }
BOOL: (TRUE|FALSE);

// I want these two keywords to be case-insensitive
TRUE:   'true';
FALSE:  'false';

// This keyword must only match exact case
YIELD options { caseInsensitive=false; }: 'yield';
```

```
parser grammar TestParser;
options { tokenVocab = TestLexer; }

program
    : statement EOF
    ;

statement
    : YIELD SPACE BOOL
    ;
```

In other words, setting `options` at the top makes it the default, unless it is overriden for a particular Token by using the form:

```
TOKEN opens { caseInsensitive=true|false; }
    : VALUE
    ;
```